# Program received signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference

Tags: linux, fortran, gfortran

```
program height_sand
        implicit none
    integer tmax, nmax
    real  zmax, maxx
     parameter (nmax=200000)
    real  x1(nmax),y1(nmax),z1(nmax),teta
        !real d, zmax, xmax
    integer  t,ntot
    integer  i, j, id, tip(nmax)
    open(unit=1,file='vmdfile.xyz')
    open(unit=3,file='height.dat')
    ntot=3000
        tmax=51
        maxx=0
        zmax=0

      do t=1,tmax
          read(1,*)
          read(1,*)


      do i=1,ntot
         read(1,*)tip(id),x1(id),y1(id),z1(id)

          if (z1(id).gt.zmax) then
           zmax=z1(id)

        end if

         if (x1(id).gt.maxx) then
          maxx=x1(id)   
       end if

           end do

          teta=zmax/maxx
          write(3,*)t,zmax,teta
    end do


      !110 format(I8, f15.6)
    END
```

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info (`gfortran -g -Wall`). Use the debugger (`gdb`). If possible, switch to a recent version of Fortran (at least Fortran 2003)

Comment: This is not a minimal example, because without input files, we cannot reproduce the problem.

Comment: Compile with run-time subscript checking.  With gfortran, `-fcheck=all` or `-fcheck=bounds`.   This cause the compiler to find the problem identified by High Performance Mark.

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
         read(1,*)tip(id),x1(id),y1(id),z1(id)
```

may well be the source of the error you report.  At the time it is executed `id` has not been given a value.  If you have assumed that it would be automagically set to `0` then (a) you've assumed wrong and (b) `tip(0)` is an invalid array element reference anyway since Fortran indexes start at `1` (unless you specifically set them to another start value which the code shown doesn't).

I strongly suspect you've shown us a half-baked code since the loop control variables (`tmax` and `ntot`) are not used inside the loops.